# addClass not working. Are my selectors not specific enough?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $( ".background" ).fadeOut();
       $("a, h1").addClass("fade");
    } else {
        $( ".background" ).fadeIn();
       $("a, h1").removeClass("fade");
    }
});
```

```css
//Add Class
.fade
  color: #BBB

//Main
body
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  font-family: Helvetica

.header
  width: 100%
  height: 100px
  position: fixed
  top: 0px
  z-index: 3
  .background, .labels
    position: absolute
    top: 0px
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
  .labels
    background-color: transparent
  .background
    background-color: #0097A7    
  h1
    float: left
    padding: 11px 0 0 40px
    color: #FFF
  .nav
    float: right
    list-style-type: none
    margin-top: 40px
    li
      display: inline
      padding-right: 60px
      a
        color: #FFF
        font-size: 19px
        text-decoration: none

.content
  width: 100%
  height: 5000px
  background-color: #FFF
```

```html
body
  .header
    .background
    .labels
      h1 JB
      ul.nav
        li 
          a(href="#") Work
        li 
          a(href="#") About Me
        li 
          a(href="#") Contact
   .content
```

Trying to make the header fade out from teal to white (which *is* working) while at the same time have the text change from white to black. I'll eventually add a transition in the css to make the text change, but for now I'm trying to get the addClass working.

Edit:
I got it working with the following:

```
.fade-in
  transition: opacity, 1s, ease
  color: #000 !important

.fade-out
  transition: opacity, 1s, ease
  color: #FFF !important
```

and

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $( ".background" ).fadeOut();
        $("a, h1").removeClass("fade-out");
        $("a, h1").addClass("fade-in");
    } else {
        $( ".background" ).fadeIn();
        $("a, h1").removeClass("fade-in");
        $("a, h1").addClass("fade-out");
    }
});
```

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: _“Are my selectors not specific enough?”_ – go use your browser’s developer tools, expect the elements and find out.

Comment: addClass is working fine, your `.fade` in the CSS isn't specific enough.

Comment: @CBroe u mean inspect right :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if this works or not.  If not can you make a fiddle? I can definitely fix it but your markup isn't displaying right.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $( ".background" ).fadeOut();
        $("h1, li a").addClass("fade");
    } else {
        $( ".background" ).fadeIn();
        $("h1, li a").removeClass("fade");
    }
});
```

Comment: You can combine selectors: `$('h1, li a').addClass();`

Comment: Thanks wasn't 100%.  Definitely combine these selectors then for performance.